# CanCan gem with nested resources and :find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

Im using CanCan `load_and_authorize_resource` helper method for fetching resources and generating authorization, but I have a nested resource like this

```
load_and_authorize_resource :company
load_and_authorize_resource :accountings, :through => :company, :class => 'Departments::Accounting'
```

But I need
@accountings be found by another attribute rather that the Departmets::Accounting id and give a value to that attribute, for example

`@accountings = @company.find_by_period_id(@period.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with two extra options:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :accountings,
    :through => :company, :class => 'Departments::Accounting',
    :find_by => :attr, # :period_id in your example
    :id_param => :something # this searches the params hash for
                            # params[:something], and sends that
                            # value to .find_by_attr
```

Check the code for `load_and_authorize_resource` [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb).